# Angular, binding model to ng-repeat passed into directive (with repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to bind a model to a repeat on a directive that has a repeat inside of it. On the outside I have it looking like this

```
 <div flex="25" ng-model="filterList">
     <div ng-repeat="filter in searchResults.filters" class="builder-result-filters" ng-model="filterlist.filter.name"></div> 
 </div>
```

So I am trying to bind everything inside of a model called filterList, then the first repeat would bind the first repeat by it's name. Then inside the directive it looks like so :

```
<div>
<ul>{{filter.name}}
    <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterlist.filter.value">{{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
Filters : {{filterlist}}
</div>
```

(trying to print out the model to see if its working)

so the initial data being passed in looks like :

```
"filters": [{
"name": "state",
"values": ["Saved", "Committed", "Published"]
},{
"name": "discipline"
"values": ["Marketing"]
}]
```

And basically I want to make a model that would output like this (based off those repeats)

```
{
  {state : {{"saved" : true, "Committed" : false , "Published" : true}},
  {discipline : {{"marketing" : true}}
}
```

Or something similar. Bonus points if I could just get the items inside to be in an array and just show up if the input is checked so like  :

```
{
  {state : ["saved", "Published" ]},
  {discipline : []}
}
```

So the items not checked would not show up. That is the end goal at least. For now I'm just trying to get these to all bind to 1 model.

So I'm partially able to achieve what I'm looking to - I tried something like this :

```
 <div>
<ul >{{filter.name}}
    <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testingModel[filter.name][value]">{{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
Filters : {{testingModel}}
</div>
```

And this spits out :

```
  {"discipline":{"Marketing":true},"state":{"Saved":true,"Committed":true}}
```

I'm wondering if there is a quick and dirty way to convert the checkboxes to an array that would add or remove the value depending on if it were true or false - like this :

```
 {"discipline":["Marketing"],"state":["Saved"]}
```

Assuming I unchecked the committed there.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` can read from an array, but can't push() or splice().

So write your own directive to bind an array to checkboxes:

```
.directive('awArray', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      array: '=awArray',
      value: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.value);
        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (event.target.checked) {
            if (index < 0) scope.array.push(scope.value);
          } else {
            if (index >= 0) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"><input type="checkbox" array="ctrl.selection" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</li>
```